# Ruby Enumerable with underlying Hash

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have a class that uses `Enumerable` and `Forwardable` mixins. The things is that even though `#each` has been implemented (or delegated), `#member?` (which also comes with `Enumerable`) is not working properly.

```
require "forwardable"
class RestrictedHash
  include Enumerable
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegators :@hash, :[], :[]=, :each

  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end
end

r_h = RestrictedHash.new
r_h[:a] = []
r_h.member?(:a)       #=> false
r_h.member?(:a, [])   #=> Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
r_h.member?([:a, []]) #=> true

h = {}
h[:a] = []
h.member?(:a)         #=> true
h.member?([:a, []])   #=> false
```

Any ideas of why I am getting this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `each` method on a `Hash` yields pairs of key and value so for your example `@hash`:

```
irb(main):001:0> h = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> h[:a] = []
=> []
irb(main):003:0> h.each { |i| puts i.inspect }
[:a, []]
```

This means that when the implementation of `member?` in `Enumerable` uses `each` to check if the value specified is a member it will successfully find `([:a, []]` but not the key `:a` on its own.

In the `Hash` class itself `member?` is [implemented to call rb_hash_has_key](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0884d0b944de777d22b963dda47294d939c9fd90/hash.c#L3900).

Comment: So although Hashes implement the "interface" Enumerable, it actually implements the methods instead of just including Enumerable?

Comment: I'm not certain of the exact details of this. The short answer is that with MRI (the reference implementation of the Ruby) `Hash` is implemented in C rather than as Ruby code and all the methods from `Enumerable` have C implementations in the source I linked. If you check that code on GitHub you'll also see a line `rb_include_module(rb_cHash, rb_mEnumerable)` now I'm not sure if that actually adds any implementation or just causes `Enumerable` to be listed in `Hash.ancestors` so that `Hash` can be treated as a class that includes `Enumerable`. Sorry that's not more definitive!

Comment: I made a script to analyse which methods were overridden or not. It turns out that Hash has a lot of methods from `Enumerable`, but it overrides some methods contained in `Enumerable`. The script is this:

`Enumerable.instance_methods.each { |method| puts "#{method} #{Hash.new.method(method.to_sym).owner}" }`